# Acknowledging that you've read a comment

Tags: discussion, comments, voting

So, the basis of this question revolves around "comment discussions".

In my year-ish being around on here, I've seen several situations where a short discussion in the comments of a question or answer has been concluded with a statement, and the other person wanted to acknowledge that they have read it. Adding another comment would be pointless, so often they just upvote that last comment.

The SE definition is that "This comment adds something useful to this post", which often it does not. Also, since upvotes are anonymous it has to be assumed that the upvote was that person, and not a random user.

Is there any acceptable way to do this without upvoting? If there isn't: Is it worth adding at all? Simply making upvotes on comments "non-anonymous" could add a little meaning to it, but I'm not even sure if upvoting a comment just to say you've read it is acceptable. The whole point of voting is that it is anonymous.

Of course, it isn't necessary to show that you've read a comment, but many people do it anyway.

For an example of what I mean, see the comments of this very question:

[image: Upvoted.]

Comment: I personally usually don't do it at all. I have a chat where half of it is just single messages without context that the other person read and possibly spent time with (links, pictures, ...), but doesn't write another message to let the sender know it. But there are also checkmarks there when the chat was opened after the message was sent, so that sends information, too. On Slack and Discord I use the "reactions". Maybe SE could get a checkmark when a tagged person read it. But "read" is also difficult to determine, one could read it in the notifications view of mail, but also just read

Comment: ...something else there and not see it.

Comment: @Fabian and in messenger, most people just use the thumbs-up emoji or similar.

Comment: I usually use "OK" to either say "I read it" or "I will do as said" or similar. But if we go into more detail, we'll enter the infinite realm of emoji usage. Tip: The movie did it wrong.

Comment: I always felt it was rude to not acknowledge comments to my posts. I would usually post a quick reply and then delete it later.

Answer (score 4):

I think the fewer "comment discussions" that there are on SE sites, the better our focussed Q&A will be.

Comments are for seeking clarifications about posts so that that the questions and any answers can be made clearer for later readers.

Once they have fulfilled that purpose they are ripe for deletion.

Any useful content that does appear in a comment should be transferred into the question or answer, as appropriate, or into a new Q&A if a new question arises from it.

The best acknowledgement of a comment is to incorporate its learning into the post that it has been applied to.

Comment: I agree with this answer.  If comments I submit turn into a discussion and I end up submitting an answer (and even if I don't) I often will flag the comments after words.  In one case the comments which resulted in an answer being submitted are deleted, and in the other, a discussion that didn't go very far were deleted.

Answer (score 3):

- Upvote the comment if you personally found it useful
- Flag it if it's not useful
- Do nothing if someone else might find it useful

If you keep in mind that Stack Exchange strives to be a professional network of Q&A sites that keep distractions to the minimum and that comments are intended to just be there to assist with answering questions and should appeal to the wider audience, it becomes clear that there's no need to give any acknowledgement whatsoever that you've read a comment.

If you feel acknowledging a comment is necessary in some given scenario, you may want to consider whether you're using comments correctly.

From [the privileges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):

> **When *shouldn't* I comment?**
>
> Comments are not recommended for any of the following:
>
> - ...
> - **Secondary discussion** or debating a controversial point; please use [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) instead

---

I don't agree that "the whole point of voting is that it is anonymous".

The whole point of voting is to show that you found something useful / not useful, it being anonymous might've just been the easiest way to quantify that.

In most contexts, I don't really see the harm in having someone know you upvoted a comment.